# iOS - Limit Pinch to Zoom using CGAfineTransform

Tags: ios, quartz-2d, zooming, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to set a max and a min limit to the zooming when I use the pinch to zoom gesture

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
NSLog(@"Pinch scale: %f", recognizer.scale);
float scale = recognizer.scale;
float SCALE_MIN = 1.0f;
float SCALE_MAX = 3.0f;

if (SCALE_MIN < scale < SCALE_MAX) {
    self.view.transform = transform;
}

else {

}
```

The logic behind this, was that it would only zoom if the condition was satisfied

but this just zooms endlessly.

Comment: I'm always afraid when I see people with this much experience "making" "iOS apps"...

Comment: Your answer works :D . . . . but than again way to go on you "kind" and "tender" approach

Comment: His answer works AND is obvious. His "kind" and "tender" approach is his opinion. But then he probably sees a lot of these half researched questions that could have been fixed with a little thought and logging/breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is not Python. The `<` operator is binary and left-associative, so

```
SCALE_MIN < scale < SCALE_MAX
```

is parsed as

```
(SCALE_MIN < scale) < SCALE_MAX
```

The left hand side is either 1 or 0 (true or false), which is always smaller than `SCALE_MAX` (which is 3). So your condition is always true. (Did you not get a compiler warning regarding that?)

Hint: you need to use the logical AND (`&&`) operator to combine the two conditions.